# My gcc compiler is 64-bit but the way it handles structure padding is like 32-bit

Tags: c

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#if UINTPTR_MAX == 0xffffffff
#define SIZE 32
#elif UINTPTR_MAX == 0xffffffffffffffff
#define SIZE 64
#else
#define SIZE 69
#endif

struct Goku{
    int x,y;
    char b,c;
};

int main(){
    printf("Word size : %d bytes\n",SIZE/8);
    printf("Struct size : %lu bytes\n",sizeof(struct Goku));
    printf("Integer size : %lu bytes\n",sizeof(int));
    printf("Char size : %lu bytes\n",sizeof(char));
    return 0;
}
```

This the output

```
Word size : 8 bytes
Struct size : 12 bytes
Integer size : 4 bytes
Char size : 1 bytes
```

This is what I expected

```
Word size : 8 bytes
Struct size : 16 bytes
Integer size : 4 bytes
Char size : 1 bytes
```

I expected the structure to be 16-bytes long but it turns out to be 12-bytes

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your expectation is wrong.  Since `sizeof(int) == 4`, the size of the structure needs to be a multiple of 4 to maintain 4-byte alignment, not a multiple of 8.

Comment: structs are padded to their alignment. The alignment of a struct is the largest alignment of any of its members. The largest alignment is that of int. Int has 4 byte alignment

Comment: The only thing that's being done wrong here is expecting specific padding from a compiler. Just because the hardware platform supports a largest int value of 64 bits does not mean that its optimal memory alignment would also be 64 bit, for various datatypes. hardware is far more complex, these days.

Comment: @Homer512 what if we use a structure inside another structure. How will the padding be calculated then?

Comment: Since the largest alignment of the elements determines the alignment of the containing structure, you can recursively determine the alignment up to the outmost structure.